# how to union the three list and return the answer as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, union

```
l1 =[23, 15, 2, 14, 14, 16, 20 ,52] 
l2 =[2, 48, 15, 12, 26, 32, 47, 54] 
l3 =[4, 78, 5, 6, 9, 25, 64, 32, 59] 
flist =list(set(l1) |set(l2)| set(l3))
print(f'union of three sets:{flist}')
```

It gave me the error below:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the code you've supplied.

Comment: Are you using "list" as a variable or function definition somewhere within scope, overwriting the built-in function?

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your error. When I ran your code, it worked just fine, and this is the output-

> union of three sets:[64, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 78, 20, 23,
>   25, 26, 32, 47, 48, 52, 54, 59]

But to answer your question you put in title, it can be done easily-

```
l1 =[23, 15, 2, 14, 14, 16, 20 ,52] 
l2 =[2, 48, 15, 12, 26, 32, 47, 54] 
l3 =[4, 78, 5, 6, 9, 25, 64, 32, 59]

l4 = l1 + l2 + l3 #concatenating the three lists to an empty list

print("The union of three lists is: " + str(l4))
```

In this way, you print a list into the terminal which contains all the elements of the previous three lists.

If you do not want one element to appear more than once, just change the last line as-

```
print("Union of three lists is: " + str(list(set(l4))))
```

This will output-

> Union of three lists is: [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 20, 23, 25,
>   26, 32, 47, 48, 52, 54, 59, 64, 78]

What I am essentially doing is adding all items of those lists to a newly created list, and then making it into a set so that no element is repeated. Then changing the set back to list and printing it as a string.

You can add elements to a new list using iteration, the extend() method or even list comprehension.

Comment: Why create the list `l4=[]` instead of directly assigning `l4=l1+l2+l3`? Also, the print statement can be written as `print("..."", l4)` without the space at the end of the string

Comment: @GarethMa , yes you are right. You do not need to initiate l4 as concatenating does it automatically. Here, I am using set() because it removes all the repeated elements and keeps only one of each, in case the user wants to do that. And I am making it into a list as the user clearly stated that he wants to output as a list. Otherwise, if you do not care about repeated elements, what you are saying would work.

Comment: @GarethMa The space at the end of the string is added just for aesthetics, nothing else.